# Visual basic - trying to delete a value from a combo box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, combobox

I am trying to remove a value from a combobox, The combobox is on a layout panel. I'm getting the value which should be removed from a database which has been linked, I know the connection to the database works (I am copying it form another part of my program) I just cant find the correct way to remove it from the combobox. The line which is causing issues is :

```
'if date in data is over a week ahead data is not displayed' 
If bookingDay = "Monday" And ((bookingDate - Today()).TotalDays < 7) Then 
   Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls("cbomonp" & period).Remove = room
   If length > 1 Then
      Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls("monp" & period + 1).Remove = room
  End If
End If
```

Comment: If you want to remove from a combo, remove the combobox *items*.  There is no reason to obscure the code with `TableLayoutPanel1.Controls` if you know the name of the control.

Comment: @user3697824, the control name appears to be being constructed, probably using an index or the like, so using the form's own field for that control may not be possible.  It may also be that the control was added at run time, given that it's in a `TableLayoutPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

`Remove` is a member of the `Items` collection of the `ComboBox`, not of the `ComboBox` itself.  Also, it's a method, not a property, so you call it and pass the item to remove rather than assigning the item to it.

```
DirectCast(Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls("monp" & period + 1), ComboBox).Items.Remove(room)
```

If you have `Option Strict On`, which you should, then the cast is required because you only get a `Control` reference back form the `Controls` collection and that doesn't have an `Items` property.

Comment: Thank you! IM quite new to Vb in general so still learning the ropes, and i cant call the individual combobox as it has to be done for like 30+ comboboxes, but ill try DirectCast(Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls("monp" & period + 1), ComboBox).Items.Remove(room) when i get back to college. Thank you for the feedback!